# Write-Host causes blank lines when redirected to a file

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

The snippet

```
powershell { Write-Host "a"; Write-Host "b" } > test.txt; Write-Host "File contents:"; cat test.txt; rm test.txt
```

prints

```
a
b
File contents:
a


b
```

Why are there 2 blank lines after every `Write-Host` call in the text file?

Even more confusing is the behavior when we redirect all streams to a file:

```
powershell { Write-Host "a"; Write-Host "b" } *> test.txt; Write-Host "File contents:"; cat test.txt; rm test.txt
```

prints

```
File contents:
a


b


a
b
```

Now the file contains everything twice, first with 2 blank lines and then normally. Why does the file contain everything twice now?

Comment: `powershell " Write-Host 'a'; Write-Host 'b' "`

Answer (score 0):

Your script does the following:

**Write-Host "a"** Writes `a[CR][LF]` to `stdout`. Then powershell for some reason* adds `[LF]` to it and stores it as an element in return list. When it prints return list, it prints each element as `[$value.toString()][CR][LF]`.

This gives you result that `Write-Host "a"` becomes `a[CR][LF][LF][CR][LF]` in output.

* *Needs investigation. Possibly it's `if value from stdout and ends with [CR][LF]`. Again, stdout is not supposed to work as pipeline in powershell, because powershell has it's own pipeline of objects.*

---

Powershell's `Write-Host` is not designed to be catched to output. Instead, there is `Write-Output` command, or `return`.

There is no *good* built-in command to output data both to file and to stdout except `Tee-Object`, but this does some different thing.

You should avoid using powershell's `stdout` output as `stdin` for other commands, as it can cantain `better-look enchancements`, `truncated parts` or `line wraps` that you can not expect. If you can not avoid it, use `Write-Output` and void any possible output with `[void]` or `.. | Out-Null`. All unhandled returns from any operations (like, `new-item`) will be passed to `stdout`

---

```
powershell {Write-Output "a" ;Write-Output "b"} > test.txt; Write-Host "File contents:"; cat test.txt; 
powershell {Write-Output "a" ;Write-Output "b"} | Out-File 'test.txt' ; Write-Host "File contents:"; cat test.txt; 
powershell { @('A';'B') | Out-File 'test.txt' } ; Write-Host "File contents:"; cat test.txt; 
powershell { @('A';'B') | Tee-Object -FilePath 'test.txt' | % { Write-Host "+ $_" } } | Out-Null ; Write-Host "File contents:"; cat test.txt; 
powershell {Write-Host "a" -NoNewline;Write-Host "b" -NoNewline} > test.txt; Write-Host "File contents:"; cat test.txt;
```

Comment: According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-7.1) `Write-Host` writes to the information stream which should be as good as any other stream for redirection shouldn't it?

Comment: Also, I'm using `Write-Host` to explicitly write to the console. I don't want these entries to end up in the pipeline! They are purely logging statements. In the end I want to redirect every output from the process to a log file.